# Cordova NFC Plugin working but raises no event

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, phonegap-plugins, nfc

I am using the phonegap-nfc plugin to read NFC tags in my cordova app. I also included the uses-permission tags in the AndroidManifest.xml.
My Typescript-Code is:

```
module myapp.nfcRead {

export class NfcCtrl {
    private status:string;

    constructor(private $cordovaNfc:any, private $cordovaNfcUtil:any) {
        this.status = "nfc";
    }

    public readNFC() {
        console.log("trying to find nfc");
        this.$cordovaNfc.then((nfcInstance:any) => {
            nfcInstance.addNdefListener((nfcEvent:any) => {
                this.status = "NFC Detected";
            })
                .then(
                //Success callback
                (event:any) => {
                    this.status = "Reading NFC";
                    console.log("Reading NFC");
                },
                //Fail callback
                (err:any) => {
                    this.status = "error";
                    console.log("error");
                });
        });
        this.$cordovaNfcUtil.then((nfcUtil:any) => {
            this.status = nfcUtil.bytesToString("some bytes");
        });
    }
}

NfcCtrl.$inject = ['$cordovaNfc', '$cordovaNfcUtil'];
angular.module('myapp.nfcRead', ['ngCordova.plugins.nfc']).controller('NfcCtrl', NfcCtrl);}
```

If i start the App in the browser and i call the method "readNFC()" the status remains "nfc". If i deploy the app on my android phone and i call the "readNFC()"-function and NFC is disabled, the status is "error". After activating NFC and calling the function again, it says "Reading NFC". Now i want to read NFC tags, but the status doesn't change. (no event is raised)

I downloaded an app from the Google Play Store to see if tags are discovered:
(app: NFC Tools)
[NFC Tools output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pukB.png)

Do you have any tip for me?
Thank you

Comment: Have you found a solution? thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using [nfc.addNdefListener](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc#nfcaddndeflistener) which will only find tags that contain NDEF messages.

The [screenshot from NFC Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pukB.png) says your tag is NDEF Formatable, so I don't think it contains an NDEF message.

You can change your code to use [nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc#nfcaddtagdiscoveredlistener) or [nfc.addNdefFormatableListener](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc#nfcaddndefformatablelistener). It's fine to have multiple listeners. Android will call the most specific listener for the tag that is scanned.

Alternately, you can use NFCTools to write an NDEF message onto the tag. Then try reading it with your exiting code.